# Make center <ul><li></li></ul> tag

Tags: html, css

How do I make center the list in the `<div>` tag? Below is coding that I currently use for the menu.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0d47a1;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.topnav li {float: left; zoom: 1;}
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #1976d2;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working version, with a  bit changed CSS. It's using set widths, but that is mostly fine, since we'er using dynamic sizes.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;}
div {
    background-color: #0d47a1;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  }
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
  width: 25em;
}
ul.topnav li {display: inline-block;, text-align: center; min-width: 8em; }
ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #1976d2;}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Working great. Thank you!